# Having at most one page-wide table in each page of a two column document

Tags: tables

I've written several papers, and in some of them I had couple of page-wide tables in two column environment of the paper. My problem with this tables is when they come immediately after each other, I don't want them to be like that, it looks ugly. To manually resolve this problem, I had to shift the tables in `.tex` file. But, this is very bothering and time consuming, given to several modifications which you have to exert, say, after each review. My question is: Is there any trick to make LaTeX put only one table in each page? I'm using `IEEEtran` class, under `pdfLaTeX` typesetting engine.

For instance, have a look at the fourth page of the sample code, there are two page-wide tables after each other.

Regards..

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabu,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\title{My Beautiful Lovely Title}
\author{MHA, MT, AR}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Some Keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{I}{NTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[40-45]
\subsection{Contributions}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Paper Organization}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Description}
\lipsum[20]
\section{Problem Formulation}
\lipsum[10-15]
\section{Case Study}
\lipsum[20-25]
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Table one}
    \tabulinesep = 1mm
    \begin{tabu} to\linewidth {X[2,l,m]*{2}{X[2,c,m]}X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]}
        \toprule
        EVs & Capacity [kWh]& \mbox{Usable Capacity [kWh]}& \mbox{Full Charging Time [h]} & \mbox{Charging Efficiency [$\%$]} & Battery Power [kW]\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{\small BMW i3}      & 22.0    & 18.8    & 3.0    & 85      &  7.4\\
        \textbf{\small Nissan Leaf} & 30.0    & 26.6    & 8.3    & 88      &  3.6\\
        \textbf{\small Kia Soul EV} & 30.5    & 27.0    & 4.6    & 88      &  6.6\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table*}%
\lipsum[30-35]
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Table two}
    \tabulinesep = 1mm
    \begin{tabu} to\linewidth {X[2,l,m]*{2}{X[2,c,m]}X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]}
        \toprule
        EVs & Capacity [kWh]& \mbox{Usable Capacity [kWh]}& \mbox{Full Charging Time [h]} & \mbox{Charging Efficiency [$\%$]} & Battery Power [kW]\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{\small BMW i3}      & 22.0    & 18.8    & 3.0    & 85      &  7.4\\
        \textbf{\small Nissan Leaf} & 30.0    & 26.6    & 8.3    & 88      &  3.6\\
        \textbf{\small Kia Soul EV} & 30.5    & 27.0    & 4.6    & 88      &  6.6\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table*}%
\lipsum[40-45]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! see, if package `stfloats`, which enable to put two column wide floats to bottom of page (if there is enough space) where it is inserted in text.

Answer (score 1):

let me elaborate my comment:

with use of package `stfloats` you can force floats with option `[b]` to be bottom of the same page where it is inserted in text, of course if there is enough space. by this you can have some tables at top and bottom of pages:

[image]

with selection of option `[t]` in all floats, the floats will be  at top of the pages. in case that there is enough space on the top of the same page where is inserted (i.e.: before the point of insertion).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage{stfloats}% <---- added

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{My Beautiful Lovely Title}
\author{MHA, MT, AR}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Some Keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords, some keywords.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{I}{NTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[40-45]
\subsection{Contributions}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Paper Organization}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Description}
\lipsum[20]
\section{Problem Formulation}
\lipsum[10-15]
\section{Case Study}
\lipsum[20-25]
\begin{table*}[b] % <--- changed, 
                  % with [t] table will be on top of the (same) page (3)
    \centering
    \caption{Table one}
    \tabulinesep = 1mm
    \begin{tabu} to\linewidth {X[2,l,m]*{2}{X[2,c,m]}X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]}
        \toprule
        EVs & Capacity [kWh]& \mbox{Usable Capacity [kWh]}& \mbox{Full Charging Time [h]} & \mbox{Charging Efficiency [$\%$]} & Battery Power [kW]\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{\small BMW i3}      & 22.0    & 18.8    & 3.0    & 85      &  7.4\\
        \textbf{\small Nissan Leaf} & 30.0    & 26.6    & 8.3    & 88      &  3.6\\
        \textbf{\small Kia Soul EV} & 30.5    & 27.0    & 4.6    & 88      &  6.6\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table*}%
\lipsum[30-35]
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Table two}
    \tabulinesep = 1mm
    \begin{tabu} to\linewidth {X[2,l,m]*{2}{X[2,c,m]}X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]X[2,c,m]}
        \toprule
        EVs & Capacity [kWh]& \mbox{Usable Capacity [kWh]}& \mbox{Full Charging Time [h]} & \mbox{Charging Efficiency [$\%$]} & Battery Power [kW]\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{\small BMW i3}      & 22.0    & 18.8    & 3.0    & 85      &  7.4\\
        \textbf{\small Nissan Leaf} & 30.0    & 26.6    & 8.3    & 88      &  3.6\\
        \textbf{\small Kia Soul EV} & 30.5    & 27.0    & 4.6    & 88      &  6.6\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table*}%
\lipsum[40-45]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

is this acceptable for you?

Comment: Absolutely, I just don't want them to be successive. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{1}
```

to your preamble then at most one spanning top float is allowed per page.